# Python sorting values and grouping them based on unique keys

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, multiple-columns

I have a list of tuple elements as below. I want to group the elements into a multidimensional row and column. For example:

say the list is "list":

```
[("Adam", "DeltaAir"),
("Bianca", "AlaskanAir"),
("Romeo", "DeltaAir"),
("Danaerys", "DragonAir"),
("Jon", "DragonAir"),
("Walter", "AlaskanAir")]
```

I would like to print out this list as:

```
------------------------------------------
Name  | AlaskanAir | DeltaAir | DragonAir
------------------------------------------
Adam                    *
Bianca      *
Romeo                   *
Danaerys                            *
Jon                                 *
Walter      *
------------------------------------------
```

What I started off with was to first find all unique elements that I want as the row header.

```
    row=[]
    for i in list:
        row.append(i[1])
    row = list(set(row))
```

Then I would iterate through elements in "row", and then build up the table. How can I easily build that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst = [("Adam", "DeltaAir"),
("Bianca", "AlaskanAir"),
("Romeo", "DeltaAir"),
("Danaerys", "DragonAir"),
("Jon", "DragonAir"),
("Walter", "AlaskanAir")]

#Create pandas DataFrame with the names from the list
df = pd.DataFrame([elem[0] for elem in lst], columns=["Name"])
#Iterate over a set (unique values) of character properties (DeltaAir, AlaskanAir, DragonAir) 
for elem in set([elem[1] for elem in lst]):
    #make a list containing spaces or *'s for every character in the list
    #depending on the property we are just iterating over and add that list 
    # as a column to the DataFrame
    df[elem] = ["*" if item[1] == elem else " " for item in lst]
```

**EDIT to your comment:**

You can use groupby and aggregate to goup the values by Name (if thats not what you meant, please clarify).

```
df.reindex(sorted(df.columns))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(sorted(list(df["Name"].unique())), columns = ["Name"])
for elem in set([elem[1] for elem in lst]):   
    df2[elem] = list(df.groupby(['Name'])[elem].agg(lambda x: "*" if "*" in x.values else " "))
```

**Adding more info**

Thanks Florian. I mean if there are duplicate names like below, it should appropriately fill the corresponding Airline row. For example: Adam and Romeo appearing twice would be like, instead of Having two seperate rows for the same name.

```
[("Adam", "DeltaAir"),
("Bianca", "AlaskanAir"),
("Romeo", "DeltaAir"),
("Danaerys", "DragonAir"),
("Jon", "DragonAir"),
("Walter", "AlaskanAir"),
("Adam", "AlaskanAir"),
("Romeo", "DragonAir")]

------------------------------------------
Name  | AlaskanAir | DeltaAir | DragonAir
------------------------------------------
Adam        *           *
Bianca      *
Romeo                   *           *
Danaerys                            *
Jon                                 *
Walter      *
------------------------------------------
```

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame([elem[7] for elem in plans], columns=["Name"]) - Whats the best way to make this list of "[elem[7] for elem in plans]" only show the unique values?  ex: df = pd.DataFrame(set([elem[7] for elem in plans]), columns=["Name"])

Comment: I mean, could you also make the "name" unique, so if there are two Adams, the * falls in the corresponding line? @Florian H. Thanks.

Comment: I also get this error "raise KeyError("Column not found: %s" % key)" when running the above.

Comment: are you sure this comes from the above code? what python version do you use?

Comment: I figured I had done a mistake while trying to understand the code and rewrite. It works perfectly Florian!

Answer (score 3):

We can do this with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([("Adam", "DeltaAir"),
("Bianca", "AlaskanAir"),
("Romeo", "DeltaAir"),
("Danaerys", "DragonAir"),
("Jon", "DragonAir"),
("Walter", "AlaskanAir")], columns=['name', 'value'])

result = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['value']).rename(columns={f'value_{col}': col for col in df['value'].unique()}).replace({col: {0: '', 1: '*'} for col in df['value'].unique()})

print(result)
```

Output:

```
       name AlaskanAir DeltaAir DragonAir
0      Adam                   *          
1    Bianca          *                   
2     Romeo                   *          
3  Danaerys                             *
4       Jon                             *
5    Walter          *
```

This converts the value corresponding to each individual to a 1 or 0 in the relevant column. Then, we simply replace 1 with `*` and 0 with the empty string.

Note that `pandas` is not necessary for the *logic*, which can be done simply, but it *is* convenient for the alignment of the table.